# ember json api camelcase/model attributes undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using the older  Ember 'JSONSerializer' because of the json format being returned by the API;

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"
  },
.....
]
```

The model requires attributes with dashes so I have created an Application Serializer

```
import JSONSerializer from '@ember-data/serializer/json';
import { dasherize } from '@ember/string';

export default class ApplicationSerializer extends JSONSerializer {
   keyForAttribute(attr) {
     return dasherize(attr)
  }
}
```

Album Model

```
import Model, { attr } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class AlbumModel extends Model {
  @attr userId;
  @attr title;
}
```

But the model attributes are still undefined

Album Template

```
<h1>album</h1>
  {{#each model as |album|}}
  <li>
  {{album.id}}
  {{album.userId}}
  {{album.title}}
</li>
  {{/each}}
```

ember-cli: 4.0.1
node: 12.10.0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyForAttribute` specifies the format of the keys in your response payload. By default Ember looks for dasherized keys--in your case, your payload is formatted in camelcase, so you'd want to look for camelized keys. To fix, just override `keyForAttribute` and return `key` without modification:

```js
keyForAttribute(key) {
  return key;
}
```